# Bot automatically removing reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a music bot. I made a queue command which shows how many songs are currently in the queue. I wanted to make it look like if the songs in the queue are greater than 10 the bot will slice it and show the rest on a next "page". To scroll between pages I wanted to use reactions. My code is working, but the Bot automatically removes its own reaction. Why is that?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args, queue, searcher) => {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    if(!serverQueue)
        return message.channel.send("**Jelenleg nincs zene lejátszás alatt!**");
    if(message.member.voice.channel != message.guild.me.voice.channel)
        return message.channel.send("**Előbb lépj be a hang szobába!**")


    let currentPage = 0;

    if(serverQueue.songs.length <= 1) return message.channel.send(`**Lejátszás alatt:** [__${serverQueue.songs[0].title}__](${serverQueue.songs[0].url})`);

    const embeds = embedGenerator(serverQueue)
    //if(serverQueue.songs.length < 12) return message.channel.send(embeds);
    const queueEmbed = await message.channel.send(`**Oldal:**: ${currentPage+1}/${embeds.length}`, embeds[currentPage])

    await queueEmbed.react('⬅️');
    await queueEmbed.react('➡️');

    const reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => ['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (message.author.id === user.id)
    const collector = queueEmbed.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter);

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '➡️'){
            if(currentPage < embeds.length-1){
                currentPage+=1;
                queueEmbed.edit(`**Oldal:**: ${currentPage+1}/${embeds.length}`, embeds[currentPage]);
                message.reactions.resolve(reaction).users.remove(user)
            }
        }else if(reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️'){
            if (currentPage !== 0){
                currentPage -= 1;
                queueEmbed.edit(`**Oldal:** ${currentPage+1}/${embeds.length}`, embeds[currentPage])
                message.reactions.resolve(reaction).users.remove(user)
            }
        }
    })
}

function embedGenerator(serverQueue){
    const embeds = [];
    let songs = 11;
    for (let i = 1; i < serverQueue.songs.length; i += 10){
        const current = serverQueue.songs.slice(i, songs)
        songs += 10;
        let j = i-1;
        const info = current.map(song => `${++j}. [${song.title}](${song.url})`).join('\n')
        const msg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`**Lejátszás alatt:** [${serverQueue.songs[0].title}](${serverQueue.songs[0].url}) \n ${info}`)

        embeds.push(msg)
    }
    return embeds;
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "queue",
    aliases: ['q']
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure why it is removing your bot's reactions. The only place in this code where reactions are removed is in your `ReactionCollector`, so consider adding a `if (user.bot) return;` to the top of your `collector.on("collect")` callback (or add something similar into the collector's filter itself). It that does not solve the issue, then your issue is being caused by something outside of the provided code, most likely.

Comment: Well, that didn't solve the problem, maybe it has to do something with my bot role, - I checked giving reactions everywhere and it's still removing it.

Comment: Does any part of your bot's code have a line like this: `client.on("messageReactionAdd")`? If so, some section of that part of the code is causing the issue. If not, I have no clue what the issue is.

Comment: I do have another reactionCollector (same as in this code and that doesnt work too) but it's in an another file and it's not getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem.It turned out that my other bot had a reaction event which removes reactions on messages after like 4 seconds.I didn't add an if(message.author.bot) return; line to that so it removed the reaction all the time.